# Is this operation safe?

Tags: java, iterator, containers

Is this operation safe? 
if not, in order to do the same thing, how to write the code??

```
Set<Object> set;

......

for (Object o: set) {
    if (some_condition) {
        set.remove(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not - because you aren't allowed to modify a collection you're iterating over, other than via the iterator. There are various options for fix this. Here's one:

```
for (Iterator<Object> iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
{
    Object value = iterator.next();
    if (someCondition)
    {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Another option is to build a separate list of items to remove, and then remove them all *after* you've iterated over the set:

```
List<Object> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Object x in set)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        itemsToRemove.add(x);
    }
}

set.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
```

Comment: @Sean: That's what I get for typing while I'm about to go to a meeting :)

Answer (score 2):

No - the first time your condition passes, you'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown on the next iteration.

In general, it is not safe to modify a collection *directly* while iterating over it, and iterators are "fail-fast" in this situation (because on the whole while they can detect changes, there's no general way to work out how to cope with them).

In this situation, one idiom that does work is to use the Iterator's own `remove()` method.  Removing the element in this controlled fashion keeps the iterator aware of what is happening, and has consistent semantics for what should happen to the iteration order, and so works as you would expect:

```
Iterator<Object> iter = set.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   final Object o = iter.next();
   if (some_condition) {
      iter.remove();
   }
}
```

Note however that `remove()` is an "optional operation", and not all collections' iterators support it.  If you're stuck in this situation, an alternative that will always work is to take a copy of the set, iterate over *that* and remove the objects from the *original* set, like so:

```
Set<Object> copy = new HashSet<Object>(set);
for (Object o: copy) {
    if (some_condition) {
        set.remove(o);
    }
}
```

Because the iteration is over `copy`, while the modifications happen to `set`, no concurrent modification occurs and the iterator is happy.

Comment: That's "always work" so long as the set supports removing in general, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Now, it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The `for()` loop uses an `Iterator` internally that keeps an edit count and if that edit count doesn't match the backing `Set`'s edit count, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Of course this depends on the actual implementation of the collection, but that's the documented behavior, e.g. in [the `HashSet` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's
>   iterator method are fail-fast: if the
>   set is modified at any time after the
>   iterator is created, in any way except
>   through the iterator's own remove
>   method, the `Iterator` throws a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus,
>   in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails
>   quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic
>   behavior at an undetermined time in
>   the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<Object> set;

    ......

    Set<Object> objectsToBeDeleted = new HashSet<Object>();
    for (Object o : set) {
        if (some_condition) {
            objectsToBeDeleted.add(o);
        }
    }

    for (Object o : objectsToBeDeleted) {
        set.remove(o);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of the second loop, use `set.removeAll(objectsToBeDeleted)`